# Java store sql request in object

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to store an sql request into an object so I can load/save information from this object.

Unfortunalty it seems I miss something... But I dunno what :D

When I execute my code I get an error saying :

"java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [B"
(I catch this message in ClassCastException)

Here is what I do :

```
public static CatalogueClients chargementClient() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    CatalogueClients maliste = new CatalogueClients();
    try {
        dbConnection = OpenConnexion.getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM client");
        while (result.next()) {
            byte[] st = (byte[]) result.getObject(1);
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(st);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            maliste = (CatalogueClients) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            bais.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassCastException cce){
        System.out.println(cce.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return maliste;
}
```

Here is what CatalogueClients look like :

```
public class CatalogueClients extends ArrayList<Client> {
private static CatalogueClients instance;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String Afficher() {
    return (Input.returnOption("Mes clients: "));
}
    public static CatalogueClients getInstance() throws SQLException {
            if (instance == null) {
            instance = Serialization.chargementClient();
        }
    return instance;
}
```

Can you guys please help ?

Thanks

Comment: It seems the database returns an `Integer` for the first column of this result set. What column type does it have in the database table definition?

Comment: Indeed the first column of my table is an Integer. I have integers and strings in this table. How should I deal with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify datatype of first column in table (which is returned by query) and modify code accordingly. As per error message mentioned, it is clear that you are receiving Integer value as value of first column.

```
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
Client client=null;
      try {
            dbConnection = OpenConnexion.getDBConnection();
            statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM client");
            while (result.next()) {
                client = new Client();
                client.setId(result.getInt(1));
                //Map other properties likewise here
               clients.add(client);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassCastException cce){
            System.out.println(cce.getMessage());
        } finally {
            maliste ==clients; // set list here
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So how should I proceed ? Because I have integers and strings in my table.
For each position I need to store the value in a variable and write everything in the object ?
Like :

`int someValue = result.getInt(1);`
`mylist = someValue.readObject();`

Comment: Assuming CatalogueClients contains a list, add each value to this list. maliste.getList().add(someValue);

Comment: Share code of class CatalogueClients for more clarity

Comment: I edited my post to integrate a part of code class CatalogueClients

Comment: @horakiel refer modified post